# Moving an element from right to left using CSS3 transitions on load of the document

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transitions

I want to add a transition property to an element which contains text coming from an angular controller.

I want to move it from right to left when the document loads. Is there any way to do that. here is my sample code.

**Index file excerpt**

```
<div class="logArena">

  <ul class="timeline">
    <li ng-repeat="log in changelogCtrl.logs | orderBy: '-dateObj'">
      <span class="direction-l">
        <span class="time-wrapper">
            <span class="time">
               {{log.date}}
            </span>
          </span>
      </span>

      <div class="direction-r">
        <div class="flag-wrapper">
          <div class="flag">

            <span id="axis">
              <span class="move-left">
                <strong>{{log.module}}</strong>&nbsp;<strong class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></strong>&nbsp;{{log.subModule}}
              </span>
            </span>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          {{log.desc}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> CSS Except (Right now I tried it with hover but it didn't work too, but I want it to automatically come from right to left on page load.)

```
#axis:hover .move-left{
    transform: translate(350px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Firefox **/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CSS` animation and define the values of the translation inside the keyframes. The `forwards` value will keep your element with the style of the last keyframe encountered.

**CSS**

```
.move-left {
    animation: moveleft 2s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes moveleft {
   from { transform: translateX(0); }
   to   { transform: translateX(350px); }

}
```

> [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvRPOg)

---

This will wait just until the presence of that element on the `DOM` but, if you need to wait the full document load (including images and heavy assets) just add a class (e.g. `.load`) to the `.move-left` element on `load` event of the window and fire the animation only if the class has been applied, so the JS and CSS selector would be

**Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('.move-left').classList.add('load');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.move-left.load {
    animation: moveleft 2s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use Jquery and .addClass and .removeClass.

For example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#axis').click(function(){
$('//What you want the class to be added too / Moved').addClass('move-left');
)};
)};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use animation property of CSS-3 in combination with [`translateX()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) property.

```
    .row {
        animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slide;
    }

    @keyframes slide {
        0%{ transform: translateX(100%);}
        100%{ transform: translateX(0%);}
    }
```

Check out [this answer](https://codepen.io/imnavanath/pen/xYyPzQ).